# Do/While Loop looping when condition set to false

Tags: java, loops, methods, java.util.scanner

This do/while loop will loop infinitely if it gets an error, even though error is set to false after each loop... I'm not sure how else to explain it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ErrorChecking {

    public static int inputInt(Scanner input, String console) {

        int finalInt = 0;
        int num;
        boolean error = false;

        do {
            error = false;
            System.out.print(console);
            if(input.hasNextInt()) {
                num = input.nextInt();
                String numDuplicate = Integer.toString(num);
                int numLength = numDuplicate.length();
                if(numLength == 8) {
                    finalInt = num;
                    error = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. ID needs to be 8 digits long. Please try again.");
                    error = true;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. ID needs to be 8 numbers. Please try again.");
                error = true;
            }
        } while(error);

        return finalInt;

    }

}
```

Comment: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072780/learning-and-improving-your-debugging-skills.html

Comment: @Amit Phaltankar, that's not really relevant to my question. Also, the error exists ONLY within this method, I've checked the other programming to make sure there was no other confliction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `input.hasNextInt()` ever returns `false`, then your loop is going to run forever because you do nothing to advance the input and it will return `false` on every iteration. My guess (without more details about your program's behavior) is that this is what's going on.

You need to somehow consume the current input to clear the error condition. The logic for doing this depends on what you're expecting as input.

Comment: Would you like the project folder so you can look for any other problems?

Comment: Would an input.nextLine() work? I use that with nextInt()'s for consuming the newline.

Comment: @AfterShock360 - That sounds reasonable if you're expecting one int per line. Or perhaps just a call to `next()` to consume the next token.

Comment: Alright, after some fiddling about, it worked. Thanks @Ted Hopp! I'm still only a year into coding, so this stuff isn't obvious for me(yet)